# C# implicit conversion without cast

Tags: c#

I am converting VB.net code to C# and I am facing a problem. With VB.net, I have functions that use OBJECT parameters. These parameters are usually of 2 differents types which have the same methods that I need. Example:

```
Public Sub test(param1 as Object)
    param1.show()
End Sub
```

With C#, I do the same kind of function, but the compiler won't accept it.

```
public void test(object param1)
{
    param1.show(); // Error on .show (not found)
}
```

I should probably cast the parameter in some way, but I need to send different types to the function. Is it possible?

Comment: Define a common interface or base class for the types, and use that as your parameter type. Or, since this is an extremely basic problem, just create a `test()` overload for each type.

Comment: This works in VB.NET because of late binding (with `Option Strict Off`), which C# disallows. It's an example of something that you can, but shouldn't do, even in VB.NET. If you enable 'Option Strict' and 'Option Explicit', your VB.NET code will not compile... The interface solution in Igor's answer works for both languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `Option Strict Off` set using `Object` is the equivalent to using `dynamic` in C#

```
public void test(dynamic param1)
{
    param1.show();
}
```

However, I really, REALLY, recommend you do not do that. `dynamic` was invented to help with writing late bound code (that is also the job `Object` served in VB6 when this feature was introduced), you really should use a class with a interface to get the strong type info for your code.

Comment: `Object` is the same in VB6 and VB.NET to the extent that both are late bound (with `Option Strict` turned off)

Comment: @CoolBots thanks, I updated my answer to remove the doubt.

Comment: Even if it is bad for the global warming, I will use dynamic. The reason is that the vb.net code worked well so, it "should" work well in C# too. Strangely, I thought that late binding were a kind evolution of polymorphism. Like in javascript, using JSON objects, you don't need to force types (anyway by forcing types, JSON would not have any purpose).

Answer (score 8):

This is why interfaces exist.

```
public interface IShowable {
    void show();
}

class YourClassFromAbove {
    public void test(IShowable param1)
    {
        param1.show();
    }
}
```

Any type passed in must implement the `IShowable` contract which solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can make separate function for each type:

```
public void test( type1  param1) { param1.show(); }
public void test( type2  param1) { param1.show(); }
public void test(dynamic param1) { param1.show(); } // for the rest of the types
```